# Fullcalendar is not defined - Rails 6

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar-5

I've got so many difficulties adding FullCalendar to my project as a newbie.
And, first of all, I dont know if I ve imported the module correctly.

I got this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: FullCalendar is not defined
```

this is what I did

```
yarn add @fullcalendar/core
yarn add @fullcalendar/daygrid
```

application.js

```
import moment from 'moment'
window.moment = moment
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core/';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
```

application.scss

```
@import '@fullcalendar/common/main.css';
@import '@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
```

view

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

        ....
    }
});

  // render the calendar
  calendar.render();
});
</script>
```

// Solved thanks to max

```
global.FullCalendar = require("@fullcalendar/core/");
```

Comment: You have to explicitly make `FullCalendar` a global in order to reference it from an inline script tag. But a better idea is to skip inline script tags altogether and keep your JavaScript in webpacker instead of in a tangled mess spread across your views.

Comment: try simply `new Calendar` instead of `new FullCalendar.Calendar` as per the example at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6